# iCloud mail: Is there a way to block emails from an address for a week?

Tags: icloud, email

A friend of mine is sending many emails every day and I would like to be notified about his emails only once per week.

Is there a way to avoid to receive emails in the inbox until the week later? and disable notifications for those emails only?

What I want:
- I want still receive his email but read all of them let's say on Mondays only
- I don't want to get notifications every time I receive an email from him
- I don't want his email in the inbox until Monday

Answer (score 1):

As Richard Dickins you can set a rule on the server this can be done on iCloud as well as Google and I think on most others.

You create a new folder and set a rule to send the mail there so not in inbox or showing a notification or adding to the count of unread,  but you have to add a separate reminder say in Calendar setting the alert as an email to remind you to read the mail.

You can also do this on OS X mail if that is the only mail reader you use, this can be automated with Applescript to copy these messages back to the Inbox

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gmail account you can create a separate label just for his emails and then set a weekly reminder to check those emails of you really need it.

If you don't have a gmail account, you may still be able to do it but I am not 100% sure. You could also put his emails in the spam sections. They remain there for 30 days so you could read his emails weekly and then restore them if they are important to your inbox. Hope this helps.

RD